# Identifying parts of a Mesh without cutting the Mesh

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh

I have a model like this one

[image: human bone]

As you can see this bone is divided into several colors.

I don't want to split the object but I want each of these bones to be clicked when clicked.

Is it possible in Unity

Comment: What does `clicked` mean for you? You can at least detect which triangle was clicked and maybe find out which color it has **if these are vertex colors**. It depends a lot on your model data and what material(s) you are using

Comment: Yes, you can probably tag the vertices in the mesh similar to how skeletal animation systems work. Grouping I suppose, a lot of modelling programs support vertex grouping but I'm not sure if unity has a native implementation or can read the groups.

Comment: Are those vertices weighted ? If not you need te group those verticies in cluster and assign to each cluster some type of collider and work with raycast to trigger clicks.

Comment: @derHugo clicked mean is i detect part name i succed detect color but i don't detect part name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i cleard this problems with hit.texturecoord